# Matplotlib: transform axis label [0,22,1] to not label from 0 but label only at odd numbers [1,3,5]

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 22 samples on x-axis, the default label is 0,1,2,3,...,21 ([0,22,1]). I want the label to show only at the location of odd numbers. Is it possible to use np.arange? As I still need column 0 but without label.

If np.arange cannot do, what should I use?

---

Additional info

I tested

```
plt.xticks(np.arange((0,22,1), np.arange(1,22,2)))
```

but it changed the first column to be 1 and compressed everything to first 11 columns. I want it to leave space for even number and label only odds.

Comment: Is this about `np.arange` or about matplotlib axis labels?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I too focus on fixing np.arange but in fact, it should be matplotlib. Thanks. I updated my question.

Comment: If you convert it to strings, you could make every other label empty, no? Something like `plt.xticks([str(v) if x % 2 == 1 else "" for x in range(22)])`. Probably not the most elegant way of going around the problem however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you want the ticks' positions and the labels to be the same, so you need to set them to be the same. If you want odd numbers only, you may indeed use `np.arange(1,22,2)`. The call in matplotlib would then be

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,22,2), np.arange(1,22,2))
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Sorry for previous comment about error. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to control tick positioning using the [`matplotlib.ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module, rather than setting them explicitly using `plt.xticks`. This is because if you use `plt.xticks`, you lose the ability to move around in interactive mode and have the ticks update as the plot area changes.

Unfortunately in this case, I don't *think* any of the existing `Locators` in `matplotlib.ticker` will work in this case (although I'm happy to be proven wrong on that one!). `ticker.MultipleLocator` can provide ticks with a spacing of 2, but can't offset them by 1 (i.e. to start at 1).

One option would be to create your own `Locator`, similar to `MultipleLocator` but with the option to offset the ticks by a given amount.

Here is an example of how that could work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np


class MultipleOffsetLocator(ticker.MultipleLocator):

    def __init__(self, base=1.0, offset=0.):
        self._base = ticker.Base(base)
        self._offset = offset

    def tick_values(self, vmin, vmax):
        if vmax < vmin:
            vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
        vmin = self._base.ge(vmin)
        base = self._base.get_base()
        n = (vmax - vmin + 0.001 * base) // base
        locs = self._offset + vmin - base + np.arange(n + 3) * base
        return self.raise_if_exceeds(locs)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)    
ax.set_xlim(0, 21)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleOffsetLocator(base=2, offset=1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

I realise this is probably overkill for the OP's question, but thought it may be useful for some future readers.